# Closure Compiler Serverside Source Map Parsing

Tags: javascript, c#, google-closure-compiler

I am looking for either an existing library or guidance on building a server side source map parser. Currently I can pass errors generated by the client to the server but since the code is closure compiled it is not very useful.

What I would like to do is be able to get an error and then using the source map file parse the error into something more useful. I did a preliminary search and could not find a decent library for accomplishing this task.

Update #1: I am actually aware there is a node.js library for accomplishing this. What I am looking for in particular is a c# library if it exists before I rewrite the javascript.

Comment: Hey Jonathan Wagner. Did you find any solution to this?